# Getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED only from MY PC and only from WIFI

Tags: domain-name-system

I am setting up the website melius.live and it literally works fine from all my devices using mobile data, but not from Wi-Fi (any Wi-Fi, not just a specific one). However, from anyone I ask to test it, it works for them.

I literally wrote the web app and set up the server and am the only one who is unable to access it (unless using mobile data).

Can it be related to some DNS settings? Because other people in the same Wi-Fi can access it. However, the issue is on my Mac, iPad, and iPhone.

Comment: Duplicated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69155658/webserver-incorrectly-configure-getting-err-name-not-resolved-only-from-my-pc-a

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, but it's on topic here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Does not seem very on-topic as closed because off-topic :-) The issue seems more user-centric than server-centric and in any cases lacks any useful detail. Plus duplicating things is bad, in general.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek And wet streets cause rain. :-) The question was clear enough to me that it was probably not an issue with home computing or networking, so I took a brief look and indeed it was not. That's why I left it open and answered it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Good for you I guess. You will just need to convince the people considering it off-topic that it is not. It was closed by more than one person...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS settings are wrong.

```
www.melius.live is an alias for melius.live.
melius.live has address 157.90.29.120
melius.live has address 192.64.119.21
melius.live has IPv6 address 2a01:4f8:c2c:ccb7::
melius.live mail is handled by 20 mx2.zoho.eu.
melius.live mail is handled by 10 mx.zoho.eu.
melius.live mail is handled by 50 mx3.zoho.eu.
```

You've entered an IP address belonging to Namecheap hosting, and two others belonging to Hetzner. It will be essentially random whether any particular user gets the correct address record *first* in the list and thus can access your site. I could not.

You should remove the incorrect DNS address record(s) depending on where you are actually hosting your site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I saw the same thing, however, I am not sure where I misconfigured it. See the attached screenshot:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mPXBv42

Comment: I am hosting via Hetzner so that one is correct. I am not sure where 192.64.119.21 is coming from tho.

Comment: @ReRed Was it originally there when you registered the domain with Namecheap? It is a Namecheap IP address, after all. In any case, all you need to do is remove it.

Comment: I don't know if it was there from the beginning, and there is no clear way to remove it. However, I read up a bit and some claim it stems from the URL Redirect Record. So I think it can stay.

Comment: @ReRed EH? If you leave it, then you will continue to have the problem. And a URL Redirect is completely not what you want.